# Regex match duration (time spent) HHhMMm or HHh MMm

Tags: regex, validation, time, duration

I want to validate a string which is a duration (time spent) for doing a task:

**2h35m

2h 35m**

I have a html **input** and I want to validate it.

I found the solution:

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])h([0-5][0-9]m)$
```

which works for **2h35m**

I tried

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])[h ]([0-5][0-9]m)$
```

where the character class `[h ]` will match the h char or a whitespace, but it does not work ok.

It matches the **2h35m** but don't matches **2h 35m**.

Any suggestions please? 
Thanks.

---

**EDIT**
a solution for the following formats

2
05
19
23

2h
05h
23h

01h50
1h02m

10h 30m
23h 59m
 is here:

```
^(([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])h?|([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])h ?[0-5][0-9]m?)$
```

I share a better answer for someone who will need this.

Comment: `[h ]` matches **either** an `h` or a space. `h ?` matches an `h` optionally followed by a space

Comment: Try `^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])h\s?([0-5][0-9]m)$`

Comment: Great! Thanks Mariano, ojovirtual. Both suggestions works.

Comment: But, the best result came after practicing a little here: http://regexone.com/ between their lessons. My REGEX from memory was refreshed.